# JSON in JSON encode

Tags: php, json

I am confused at how PHP `json_encode` behaves for a JSON in JSON.

Below is my shortened code:

```
public function testcase() {
    $return = array();

    $return['kOut1'] = 'valueOfKOut1';
    $return['kOut2'] = 'valueOfKOut2';

    $json = '[{"k1In1":10,"k1In2":0,"k1In3":2}, {"k2In1":7,"k2In2":6,"k2In3":5}]';
    $data = json_decode($json, TRUE);
    if (json_last_error()!=JSON_ERROR_NONE) {
        die("Error parsing json");
    }

    $elements = array();

    foreach ($data as $element) {

        $e = array();

        foreach ($element as $key=>$value) {
            $e[$key] = $value;
        }

        array_push($elements, $e);
    }

    $return['kOutLast'] = json_encode($elements); // NOTE: if $json is here, same result!

    echo json_encode($return);
}
```

Output of the script above:

```
{"kOut1":"valueOfKOut1","kOut2":"valueOfKOut2","kOutLast":"[{\"k1In1\":10,\"k1In2\":0,\"k1In3\":2},{\"k2In1\":7,\"k2In2\":6,\"k2In3\":5}]"}
```

Confusion: Why do I have `\"` (backslash and double quote) wrapping around keys in the value of `kOutLast`? It should have been `"` only. Right?

I also tried various options in `json_encode` (such as ) but still no luck. Have you got ideas?

Thanks in advance,

Info: I am coding in Code Igniter framework, XAMPP v3.2.1 (compiled May 7th, 2013).

Comment: "a JSON in JSON" --- json is nothing but a string. Stop thinking about it like something other than a string and the confusion must disappear. "It should have been " only. Right?" --- nope. Why do you think so?

Comment: @zerkms: I know JSON is just a string. My question is why keys in the value of `kOutLast` are wrapped by `\"`? Why not `"` only?

Comment: Because they are not keys, it's just a string. And as in any other string - its double quotes must be escaped as per JSON specification. Replace `\"` with `"` and try to validate the resulting JSON.

Comment: Because they are keys of the serialized object.

Comment: Oh, I see... I missed `"`. Stupid me! Thanks a lot for your very quick response

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A JSON string is terminated by `"`. If there's a `"` character in the string itself, it obviously needs to be escaped. The correct JSON string to represent the text `"` is `"\""`. It is of absolutely no concern that your string "is JSON". What matters is that it's a string which contains quotes. To encode a string which contains quotes as JSON all quotes need to be escaped with a backslash.

If what you're really trying to do is merge an existing JSON object into another JSON object, you need to decode it first:

```
$json = '[{"key":"value",..}]';
$data = json_decode($json);
$data = array('wrapper' => $data);

echo json_encode($data);
```

Comment: Great answer! Exactly what I have been looking for! Thanks a lot.